# Sole tenant nodes pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to host my project on a dedicated server, I came across with Google Cloud product [sole-tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/). I try to calculate the pricing using GCP calculator and there is only one type of machine which is `n1-node-96-624` and I will get 96 CPUcore with 624GB of RAM:

[image]

In the image above I need to pay for all the CPU and RAM that costs 3.9k$, I don't need that many CPU and RAM. Can I use a custom CPU and RAM for this sole tenant nodes? And how about the pricing?

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding you wrong, but if you just need a server to host your application, why you don't use a regular [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/)? The're relatively cheap and configurable.

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda my client persistelntly wants dedicated host

Comment: Custom machine type for sole-tenant-nodes seems like a feature request for the GCP platform. I would recommend you to create one using [this link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sole tenant nodes come in fixed sizes because that is the size of machine that Google uses. If they have 96 core machines, you can't ask to pay for just 1 core but also demand that they don't sell the other 95 to anyone else.

Note that you can run multiple instances on a single sole tenant node. So you could pay for a sole tenant node and run 96 single-core VMs on it.